# SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values 00947. 00000 - "not enough values"

Tags: sql, oracle

while inserting into new table from an existing table I am getting the error ->

> SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
> 00947. 00000 -  "not enough values".

Query I am writing is -

```sql
insert into table_2
select table_1.columnname
from table_1, table_2
where table_1.columnname = table_2.columnname;
```

Checked the row count which is same and the column on which I am applying where condition have same values in both the tables.

Comment: Table_2 needs you to supply more than one column.

Comment: Also: the `A,B` join syntax has been obsolete for **30 years** now, and should not be used.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why involve table_2 in the SELECT? A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the column you want to set when you insert rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_2 (column_name)
SELECT t1.columnname
FROM   table_1 t1
       INNER JOIN table_2 t2
       ON  t1.columnname = t2.columnname;
```

Any other columns in the destination table will be set to the default values for that column (typically `NULL` if you have not specified another default).

If `table2` has more columns that you want to set then specify more columns:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_2 (column1, column2, column3, column4)
SELECT t1.column1,
       t1.columnX,
       t1.columnY,
       t1.columnZ
FROM   table_1 t1
       INNER JOIN table_2 t2
       ON  t1.columnname = t2.columnname;
```

If you do not specify a list columns after the `INSERT INTO table_name` clause then Oracle expects you to provide a value for every column in the table. You are getting that error because the table has more than one column and you only `SELECT` a single column.